# Acceder a elemento de object(stdClass) o a un elemento de un Array [PHP]

Tags: php, json, array, string

Tengo el siguiente String:

```
"[{"id":"13","cantidad":"12"}]"
```

Ahora, quiero convertirlo a un Objeto para acceder a sus datos, aplicandole el método `(object)$string;`, devuelve:

```
{ ["scalar"]=> string(29) "[{"id":"13","cantidad":"12"}]" }
```

Y no se como acceder al valor de `id` o de `cantidad`

Si en lugar de Objecto, lo transformo en `array` obtengo:

```
 { [0]=> string(29) "[{"id":"13","cantidad":"12"}]" }
```

> Usando cualquiera de los dos métodos, cuando paso por el foreach tengo el siguiente error:

```
 Illegal string offset 'id' 
 Illegal string offset 'cantidad'
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías convertir el string a JSON y tratarlo como un array, te coloco un ejemplo del código, espero te sirva

```php
$string= '[{"id":"13","cantidad":"12"}]';

$json= json_decode($string, true);

foreach($json as $data){
    echo $data['cantidad'];
}
```

Comment: Ahora estoy en el trabajo y no tengo acá el código, yo hice esto que me pasas pero no le agregue el valor "true" a la función json_decode. Eso en que cambia?

Comment: Con el `true` le indicas que el objeto devuelto sea un array asociativo.

Comment: Perfecto, se solucionó cuando hice uso del parametro ``true``, se agradece mucho tu tiempo =)

Comment: Ja, elimine ese comentario porque me seguia equivocando, efectivamente asi salio. Gracias de nuevo