# Como acceder a un array dentro de un object(stdClass)

Tags: php, json, array

¡Hola Comunidad!

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Quiero acceder a la información de un **array** que se encuentra dentro de un de los elementos de un **object(stdClass)**, pero no he podido lograrlo.

La información la obtengo de una **API** que me devuelve un **JSON**. He consultado los siguientes enlaces:

- [Acceder a elemento de object(stdClass) o a un elemento de un Array [PHP]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328539/acceder-a-elemento-de-objectstdclass-o-a-un-elemento-de-un-array-php)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687738/echo-a-value-in-an-stdclass-object-within-an-array-within-an-object
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846665/php-access-value-of-the-array-inside-object
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495068/convert-stdclass-object-to-array-in-php

Y a lo que llegué es que no este formatenado bien en **JSON** o no este llamando bien a los elementos del **Array**

He intentado esto: echo `$Datos->productos[0]->producto_id;` Pero no me funcionó

Así obtengo el **JSON**

```
$Datos = file_get_contents($URL_API, false, $Header);
var_dump(json_decode($Datos));
```

Y el **JSON** se muestra así:

```
  object(stdClass)#1 (5) { 
     ["cantidad"]=> int(1359) 
     ["pagina"]=> int(1) 
     ["paginas"]=> int(23)
     // Solo puse uno
     ["productos"]=> array(60) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (19) { 
           ["producto_id"]=> string(6) "163346" 
           ["modelo"]=> string(9) "DSPLUGEXT" 
           ["total_existencia"]=> int(500) 
           ["titulo"]=> string(106) "Protector para Exterior IP68 / Adaptador para el Conector Tipo Plug (12 VCD) en Cámaras epcom / HIKVISION" 
           ["marca"]=> string(9) "HIKVISION" 
           ["sat_key"]=> string(8) "39121719" 
           ["img_portada"]=> string(96) "https://ftp3.syscom.mx/usuarios/fotos/BancoFotografiasSyscom/HIKVISION/DSPLUGEXT/DSPLUGEXT-p.PNG" 
           ["link_privado"]=> string(118) "http://www.productosinfo.net/s/syscom/es/15368/ca6409ee8b5e33c2593c6563d5cf9976/x/-MX$/DSPLUGEXT-HIKVISION-163346.html"
           // Solo puse uno 
           ["categorias"]=> array(8) { 
              [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { 
                 ["id"]=> string(3) "206" 
                 ["nombre"]=> string(19) "Cables y Conectores" 
              } 
           ["pvol"]=> string(4) "0.01" 
           ["marca_logo"]=> string(61) "https://ftp3.syscom.mx/usuarios/fotos/logotipos/hikvision.png" 
           ["link"]=> string(41) "/producto/DSPLUGEXT-HIKVISION-163346.html"
           ["iconos"]=> array(0) { } ["peso"]=> string(4) "0.01" 
           ["existencia"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (1) { 
              ["nuevo"]=> int(500) 
           } 
           ["alto"]=> string(1) "1" 
           ["largo"]=> string(2) "10" 
           ["ancho"]=> string(1) "5" 
           ["precios"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (3) { 
              ["precio_especial"]=> string(4) "0.75" 
              ["precio_descuento"]=> string(4) "0.48" 
              ["precio_lista"]=> string(4) "1.50" }
           }
     ["todo"]=> bool(false) 
  }
```

Agradecería mucho que alguien me ayude a resolverlo.

Comment: y si le agregas `json_decode($Datos,true)` para converlirlo a lista`[array]` y tendrias que acceder `$producto = $Datos["productos"][0]; $id = $producto->producto_id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## El error

El problema es que `$Datos` no representa un JSON válido. `$Datos` es lo que obtuviste en la llamada a `file_get_contents()`, o sea, una cadena.

Por lo tanto esto es erróneo:

```
$Datos->productos[0]->producto_id; 
  ^
No es un JSON
```

## La solución

Quien te convierte los datos obtenidos en un JSON es `json_decode`. De hecho, cuando haces el `var_dump` te lo muestra correctamente. Pero **necesitas guardar el resultado de `json_decode` en una variable para luego poder usarla**.

Si lo haces así debería funcionar:

```
#Esto es una cadena
$Datos = file_get_contents($URL_API, false, $Header);
#Convertimos la CADENA $Datos a JSON y guardamos el resultado en una variable
$json=json_decode($Datos);

#Prueba... NÓTESE que NO usamos $Datos, sino $json
var_dump($json->productos[0]->producto_id);

#Hay que usar $json para obtener el valor de cualquier propiedad
echo $json->cantidad;
```